# Removing certain hover-help features in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: popup-help]The help popups that outline the indentation guides in Visual Studio (along the left side of the code editor) are killing me. If you leave the mouse near the vertical line that connects indenting braces, a giant popup appears that blocks up to 10 lines of code. 
Tapping the mouse doesn't always make this go away; you have to move the mouse LATERALLY to get away from it.  And don't get too close to the next indentation line!

This window has some use if you are at the end of 10 levels of end braces, and you need to find the end of a function or something. But overall, how can you turn this off? I don't even know what it's called.

Comment: Without a screenshot is pretty impossible to understand what you are talking about. Just take a screenshot with the snipping tool, save it to the desktop and upload it

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this by trial and error: "Block structure guides"

**Tools->Options->TextEditor->C#->Advanced**

[image]

Uncheck these and the 'problem' goes away, and all the other really helpful popups remain.